# A vessel contains $x$ amount of milk out of which $y$ amount is taken out and replaced with water $n$ times.

Tags: induction, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, recursion

There is a formula in my book for questions of type,

> A vessel contains $x$ amount of milk out of which $y$ amount is taken out and replaced with water. After $n$ such operations what will be the amount of Milk?

The formula says remaining *Milk* after $n$ such operations = $x\left(1-\dfrac yx\right)^n$

> - How can we prove this formula?

I actually somehow proved this a long time ago with the principle of mathematical induction but can't recall the second step. For $n=0$ and $n=1$ the formula is obviously true. Then we can assume that for a specific $n$ the formula holds. But I do not remember how to show the validity of formula for $(n+1)$th operation.

If there are other proofs than Induction then I would like know them. Thanks.

Comment: If you know about induction, this is a prime example of a formula that can be shown using that technique.

Comment: @Arthur Actually the first thought about the proof I had was by induction and I actually did prove it but I just have forgotton it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem for someother OP. Here you go!

[image]

Comment: Why is in the second step quantity of water left $y-y^2/x$?

Comment: @user103816 $y - y^2/x$ is just another way of writing $y(1-y/x)$.

Comment: @Arthur, Thanks for answering. you are right.

Comment: But I am still unable to understand your answer. Why is water $y(1−y/x)$ after second operation?

Comment: The ratio of water remaning after the 1st operation is $\frac{y}{x}$.  Now you are taking y amount of liquid for the second opeation.  Now the water element in that would be $y\times \frac{y}{x}$. After the second operation, the remaning water would be y amount that added in the first operation  minus  $y\times \frac{y}{x}$. Hopefully this anwers for rest of them too.

Comment: In the first operation `total liquid = milk+water = (x-y)_milk + y_water, so the ratio of milk to water after 1st operation must be (x-y)/y not x/y.